# Correct Format to send errors in Node Js and Use them in Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular5, jwt

I am practicing Node JS and Angular from past one month. But I am not sure about doing one thing. Whether I should send my errors from my node API using Headers or a JSON Object with the key as an error in my Body...

I have checked some forums, but there is no perfect answer out there. So please spend some time to answer my question guys. Thanks in advance.

Edited: I am using JSON Web Token in my Body part as JSON Format in Login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is quite subjective to answer and will definitely have multiple strategies to work with. This is what I'm doing for my APIs, hope this is useful.

- Error messages (JSON) are sent as response body having keys such as "errType" and "errDetail" and maintain this to avoid integration pain. Sometimes, if API is expected to be used by only backend developers, sending some technical error information using key as "errReason".
- Send exact response status code like 400, 413 and so on for more clarity.
- Not returning any additional header for error reporting.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Okkk I am bit new to this web api concepts...So I have some doubts.... Now if we don't find user we always send 404 request and if can't find some city we r giving some 400 request with some error message..Now front end developers use that status to find it's an error or they first search body of response for errType and find error or not????

Comment: For frontend dev, response status code is to decide which kind of error display decision needs to taken like may be red error banner for 4xx series and amber error banner for 5xx and then errType can be checked for precise information in that error banner.

Comment: Okkk then I shld first check my response in angular and then access the errStatus???

Comment: Yes. That is more like it.

Comment: Okk thanks for the answers @kunalmz...I am new to web api concepts and u cleared some of my doubts

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)